# Arduino - How could I store the value of an array to a temp variable?

Tags: arrays, arduino

I'm currently making a random number generator for the Arduino which is going to act as the lottery. I need six numbers all different and all between 1 and 50. With the code I have put together can achieve this easily but the random numbers are not quite as random and they do duplicate at times. The variables are stored into an array and not separate variables so it isn't straight forward (for me anyway) to add say OR statements etc. Also I want to keep it in a While loop and not a For loop.

Any help and advice would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the code I have put together so far:

```html
int counter = 0; // Counter to be incremented
int maxNum = 6;  // Max amount to increment to
int randNums[0]; // Random numbers array

void setup(){
  
  Serial.begin(9600);
  randomSeed(analogRead(0));
  delay(300);
  
}

void loop(){
  
  while(counter < maxNum){
    
    randNums[counter] = random(1,50);
    Serial.println(randNums[counter]);
    delay(500);
    counter++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Random number generator doesn't guarantee that numbers don't repeat. And your statement int randNums[0]; is big nonsense, you ask for crash or hang.

Answer (score 0):

I see two parts in your question:
 - the quality of the randomness
 - how to use a temp array storage (? i don't fully understand this issue)

Concerning the quality of randomness, you could have a look at this Arduino library: http://code.google.com/p/tinkerit/wiki/TrueRandom, but, as said here: http://www.instructables.com/id/Arduino-True-Random-Number-Generator/
 this is not NIST compliant. Although, I think that it is a step in the good direction.

Concerning your array issue, the first problem I see is that you reserve only 0 items in your declaration. Why? Either you reserve memory at compile time with int randNums[6], or you declare a pointer to an int, and use malloc during execution time.

HTH

Comment: Thank you I just found out about TrueRandom myself not too long ago. So if I were to add TrueRandom and randNums[6] would this solve my issues. As to answer why, I'm still quite new to this language and still finding my feet. Thank you for your reply

Comment: In C, as I told you, there is two ways of reserving memory for a structure: either by declaring a pointer to this structure, and at runtime, by using memory management functions to dynamically reserve memory you plan to use, or by pre-reserving memory, at compile-time, by declaring the number of structure elements you plan to use.
In your case, you choosed the second method, but reserved only 0 elements. This is not logic.
If was yourself, I would have a look at the TrueRandom library, which basically does what you planned with analogRead(). Give it a try, it could lead you to good direction